# ol-cesium: Is there a way to select a feature in ol-cesium and track it back to openlayers features?

Tags: openlayers-5

I have a geojson that was added as a feature vector to openlayer. All the geojson in their properties section have some additional information that I want to display on clicking a feature (eg a popup) in 3d space. I used the ol-cesium overlay example to create a pop but there isn't a way to get the feature-geojson properties just with 3d(ol-cesium) enabled.
Are there any approach to get the feature details on clicking a feature in 3d space?

Comment: found a solution and have posted in here [solution](https://github.com/openlayers/ol-cesium/issues/671)

Answer (score 1):

figured it out I think I had to do some think like this .

```
private getOlFeatureFromMouseLocationInOLCS(cesiumMouseEvent: any): OlFeature | undefined {

if (cesiumMouseEvent.position.x === 0 && cesiumMouseEvent.position.y === 0) {
    return;
}
 /**
 //hoping the below two lines have bee defined early on . 
 this._ol3d = new OLCesium({ map: this._currentMap });
 this.scene = this._ol3d.getCesiumScene();
 **/
 const pickedFeature = this.scene.pick(cesiumMouseEvent.position);
 let olFeature: OlFeature;
 if (pickedFeature.primitive) {
    olFeature = (pickedFeature.primitive.olFeature)?pickedFeature.primitive.olFeature as OlFeature : undefined;
} else {
    olFeature = undefined;
}
 return olFeature;
}
```